# React Redirect will redirect to 404 page if query param is inserted by hashHistory

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, redirect

There is a problem when using `hashHistory` provided by `react-router` on adding query param to url:

**Router** - **react-router@3.2.0**

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
    <Redirect from="*" to="/home" />
</Router>
```

Adding query param with `hashHistory`:

**JS**

```
hashHistory.push({
    query: {
        someParam: 'paramValue'
    }
});
```

**Scenario**

I am on `/contact` page and on click i want to add query param `someParam` to the url. I use above code with `hashHistory`.
Result of this action is redirection to `/home?someParam=paramValue`.

It seems that method `push()`, provided only with `query`, will treat new url as `/`. So being that as it is, `Redirect` will go to home with give parameter.

Comment: which version of react-router do you use

Comment: I use version 3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

To avoid being redirected to `/home` or any other page that is set as redirect page, pathname needs to be provided for `push()` method:

**JS**

```
const currentLocation = hashHistory.getCurrentLocation();

hashHistory.push({
    pathname: currentLocation.pathname,
    query: {
        someParam: 'paramValue'
    }
});
```

We can extract current path from `hashHistory`'s `getCurrentLocation()` method.